# Mix unsanitized data, HTML in a mustache template variable

Tags: escaping, xss, mustache

I'm trying to pass a message through to a Mustache template that looks something like this:

The url you provided, `http://example.com`, is not valid.

The user specifies the URL, so the URL needs to be escaped. However I want to put `<code>` tags around the URL, so it stands out from the surrounding text, so the code tags need to be passed through without being escaped.

I could write something like this:

```
{{text_before_url}}<code>{{url}}</code>{{text_after_url}}
```

However, the text of the message varies and it's not always going to fit that structure.

I could also try outputting the raw text with three braces, `{{{messages}}}`, and escaping the URL with something like `htmlentities($url)`, but if someone adapts the program later to pass in a new message, and passes in data without realizing it has to be escaped, then we are in big XSS trouble.

I might just be out of luck, and I understand the value of having a simple templating engine, but is there some way I can tell Mustache that the HTML tags are OK, while escaping the rest of the output?

Kevin

Comment: i have a similar problem and have found nothing so far, will check back here if i find an answer.

Answer (score 6):

Using {{variable}} inside a template for 5 > 2 will result in `5 &gt; 2`, where as the usage of {{{variable}}} (3 mustaches) will result in `5 > 2`.

Cf. documentation: https://github.com/defunkt/mustache#escaping